# Send One StatusResponse to Server or Send Multiple

Tags: java, server, response, health-monitoring

This is a best practices question I haven't quite found the answer to, so if there are resources or similar questions, please send me the link, as I have had trouble narrowing this down on Google...

I'm writing a program that will check on the health status of various services that run on our servers. Essentially, I will have a module that runs on the server and fires some scripts to check that everything is alive and well, then will send a JSON object to our monitoring station where the info will be processed and displayed, etc.

My question is whether or not I should send a response for each individual service and handle each case on the monitoring station, or if I should package all the responses from the various services into one object and unwrap everything from there.

Again, I'm looking for best practices for the situation, so if there are any resources you could point me to, or past experiences that may be applicable, I would appreciate some input.

Thanks!

Comment: The answers will be primarily opinion-based, as either alternative has advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: I was afraid of that, perhaps would it be more useful to ask about the pros and cons of each setup?